Are norm-closed convex subsets necessarily weak*-closed?
I am currently reading a paper where a norm-closed, bounded and convex subset of the dual of a normed linear space has been constructed and then the author claimed that the set is weak star-compact. Since norm-bounded weak star-closed sets are weak star-compact by Banach-Alaoglu's theorem it turns out to me that norm-closed convex subsets of the dual space has to be weak star-closed. Is this argument correct? If so, how to prove this? Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

@geetha290krm$:$ Not really. Norm-boundededness condition of the set is given. So if we can prove that the set is weak*-closed then we are done! Because norm bounded weak*-closed sets are weak*-compact by the virtue of Banach-Alaoglu's theorem. Right?

@geetha290krm$:$ You are misinterpreting what I have said. I am saying norm-boundedness condition of the set is already given in the paper. So in presence of weak*-closedness, the set would become weak*-compact. This is exactly what I was trying to prove. But I don't know whether it holds or not.

@geetha290krm It’s quite obvious in the question body that boundedness is part of the context in the paper the OP is reading, not part of the question the OP is asking. Though it might be better for the OP to specifically highlight which part is the question being asked, as there are quite a few adjectives being used in quick succession.

@geetha290krm$:$ I don't see anything wrong in the title. In fact this is what I would like to know and the answerer answered it correctly.

This is not correct. For example, the set $A$ of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ of supremum norm at most $1$ is a norm-closed, bounded, and convex subset of $L^\infty([0, 1])$, which is the dual space of $L^1([0, 1])$. But $A$ is not weak$^\ast$-closed (and thus not weak$^\ast$-compact either). Indeed, the weak$^\ast$-closure of $A$ is the entire closed unit ball of $L^\infty([0, 1])$.
To make the claim true, you would need the underlying Banach space to be reflexive, in which case the weak$^\ast$-topology and the weak topology coincide. And you do have any norm-closed, convex subset is weakly closed, by Hahn-Banach theorem.

+1. Nice example.

This is a nice answer. I understand the set you have constructed is not weak*-closed but I can't see why the weak*-closure is the entire closed unit ball in $L^{\infty} [0,1].$ Is it true that any bounded measurable function on $[0,1]$ can be approximated pointwise by a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]\ $?

@Anacardium Every measurable function is a.e. equal to a Borel function, and every Borel function is a pointwise limit of continuous functions. Every function in the approximation can be chosen to have sup norm at most $1$. Now use dominated convergence to show that a.e. pointwise convergence is enough to imply weak$^\ast$ convergence.

Here is another example, which uses that
weak-star closedness implies weak-star sequentially closedness.
The following set is an example of a norm-bounded and not weak-star sequentially closed set set:
Let $X= \ell^\infty$, which is the dual of $\ell^1$. Let
$$
C := \{ x\in c_0: \ \|x\|_\infty \le 1\},
$$
where $c_0$ is the space of sequences converging to zero. This set is bounded, closed, and convex. Now let
$$
x_n := (\underbrace{ 1,\dots,1}_{n \text{ ones}}, 0,\dots).
$$
Then $x_n \rightharpoonup^* x = (1,1,1,\dots)$ in $\ell^\infty = (\ell^1)^*$ but $x \not \in C$.
